# using Method invoke with static methods?

Tags: java

How do you invoke a static java method when one of the parameters for Method invoke `invoke(Object obj, Object[] args)`, requires an object parameter?

For example
Here I have a section of code that checks a class and locates any static methods that have no parameters, a return type of Boolean and starts with the name "test".  I am trying to invoke such methods to see if they return true though, and I am at odds at how to do so.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Class.forName(name).getDeclaredMethods().length; i++) {
    Method method = Class.forName(name).getDeclaredMethods()[i];
    if (method.getParameterTypes().length == 0 
            && method.getReturnType().getName() == "boolean" 
            && method.getName().startsWith("test", 0)) {
        if (Class.forName(name).getDeclaredMethods()[i].invoke()==true)
            System.out.println("Test" + " " + Class.forName(name).getDeclaredMethods()[i].getName() + " " + "succeeded");
    }
}
```

Comment: this done by clicking on the check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you claimed that you are checking method for `staticness`. But actually you are not. Use this to check for `static` modifier,

```
Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers());
```

Now, you can pass `null` as a first argument and an empty array as a second, to `method.invoke()` if the method is `static` with zero arguments. For example,

```
Class.forName(name).getDeclaredMethods()[i].invoke(null, new Object[0]);
```

*TIP: Don't repeat `Class.Forname()` every time. Store it in some variable and use it. Do the similar thing wherever appropriate.*

Comment: Ah, very nice.  Was wondering if there was a method to check for staticness, and what to use for the object in null...thanks